# Convert float to int implicit vs explicit (cast) discrepancy

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

```
int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
float f = 2.8f;
i1 += f;
i2 += (int)f;
f += 0.1;
i1 += f;
i2 += (int)f;
f += 0.1;
i1 += f;
i2 += (int)f;
printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
```

Output:

```
7 6
```

1. Why would implicit and explicit conversion results be different?
2. I would like results to be like the ones for implicit conversion, but without compilation warning. Is it possible?

Platform is Windows7, VS2010 or 2013.

Comment: You haven't shown the output.

Comment: can u please provide the results aswell

Comment: @grunt Do not edit your own question so much that it changes the question, especially after receiving a good answer.

Comment: @Pete Becker Disagree with edit: changing "explicit cast" to "explicit conversion".  Original terminology is correct and agrees with the C spec.  Suggest reverting.

Comment: @chux -- a cast is always explicit, so "explicit cast" is redundant. But the edit was primarily about "implicit cast". A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Conversions can be explicit (i.e., with a cast) or implicit.

Comment: @Pete Becker "Explicit cast" is used in the C spec and if it is redundant of not is irrelevant.  Now this post lacks "cast" which is certainly the term to used in `C` when code does `(int)f` as it uses a _cast operator_.  Without "cast" the post is now harder to find in searches and reduces its value and thus a poor edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To analyse this, the first job is to rewrite `a += b` as `a = a + b`.

`i + (int)f` will be computed in integer arithmetic due to the explicit cast.

But `i + f` will be computed in floating point arithmetic due to *type promotion*.

So the expressions have different types. Due to the way floating point works, the result, when converted back to an `int` *could* differ.

The moral of the story is to *not* use `+=` for mixed types, and to not ignore helpful compiler warnings.

Comment: So to answer question #2: i = (int)((float)i + f)?

Comment: " not use += for mixed types": Would you apply this to `float f = 2.8f; ... f += 0.1;` also?

Comment: I wouldn't write `f += 0.1`, no: too much going on under the hood. That said, I don't use `float` any more.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the more detailed break down of the situation, in the form of compiler generated code and values of variables (i1, i2 an f) after line-by-line execution.

```
1.  int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
2.  float f = 2.8f;
3.  i1 += f;            //i1 = (int)((float) i1 + f);  | i1 => 2,   i2 => 0,   f => 2.8 
4.  i2 += (int) f;      //i2 = i2 + (int) f;           | i1 => 2,   i2 => 2,   f => 2.8
5.  f += 0.1;           //                             | i1 => 2,   i2 => 2,   f => 2.9
6.  i1 += f;            //i1 = (int)((float) i1 + f);  | i1 => 4,   i2 => 2,   f => 2.9
7.  i2 += (int) f;      //i2 = i2 + (int) f;           | i1 => 4,   i2 => 4,   f => 2.9
8.  f += 0.1;           //                             | i1 => 4,   i2 => 4,   f => 3.0
9.  i1 += f;            //i1 = (int)((float) i1 + f);  | i1 => 7,   i2 => 4,   f => 3.0
10. i2 += (int) f;      //i2 = i2 + (int) f;           | i1 => 7,   i2 => 6,   f => 3.0
11. printf("%d %d", i1, i2);
```

Notice lines 3, 6 and 9, here i1 is converted to float due to [type promotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion) (I would recommend you to read this wiki), and then the result is converted back to integer to assign to integer L-value.

Line 5 and 8 would prompt this warning, which could be easily fixed by converting 'f += 0.1;' to 'f += 0.1f;'

> warning C4305: '+=' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'

Answer (score 4):

Because your explicit conversions are done **before** the addition (`float` `f` to `int`).
The implicit conversions are:

1. Conversion of `i1` to `float`.
2. Conversion of result to `int` **after** addition.